# Trying to run JsTestDriver in Visual Studio 2010, getting an error

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, js-test-driver

I was following some online guides to setting up JSTestDriver in Visual Studio, I can get the server to launch, but the test cannot find the server which is very odd.  Here is the error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Oh Snap! No server defined!
at com.google.jstestdriver.config.DefaultConfiguration.getServer(DefaultConfiguration.java:57)
at com.google.jstestdriver.config.Initializer.initialize(Initializer.java:97)
at com.google.jstestdriver.JsTestDriver.runConfigurationWithFlags(JsTestDriver.java:259)
at com.google.jstestdriver.JsTestDriver.runConfiguration(JsTestDriver.java:211)
at com.google.jstestdriver.JsTestDriver.main(JsTestDriver.java:144)
```

Unexpected Runner Condition: Oh Snap! No server defined!
 Use --runnerMode DEBUG for more information.

Anyone get this error message?  I can certainly provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can easily run this with command line with another sample project, so I thought about it and discovered that it is because the jsTestDriver.conf was not found.  Thus moving it back to the root of my project solved the problem, hope this help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the file is encoded as ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try passing in the following command line argument:

--config $(SolutionDir)FolderName\FolderName\jsTestDriver.conf

Which basically says going from the solution folder you will find the jsTestDriver.conf file in the following location